# eclipse plugin > java based project, how to

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i made a new plugin in eclipse that adds a new project entry that can then be used to add a new project.

however when going to project properties i get this:

[image: my project properties]

instead of this:

[image: java project properties]

so, my question is, how to get my project to also include all the java things (like: java build path, etc...), as i want this project to be based on the default java project.

how i am making the project currently is (code):

```
@Override
public boolean performFinish()
{
    if (project != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    final IProject projectHandle = wizardPage.getProjectHandle();
    URI projectURI = (!wizardPage.useDefaults()) ? wizardPage.getLocationURI() : null;
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    final IProjectDescription desc = workspace.newProjectDescription(projectHandle.getName());
    desc.setLocationURI(projectURI);
    WorkspaceModifyOperation op = new WorkspaceModifyOperation()
    {
        protected void execute(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException
        {
            createProject(desc, projectHandle, monitor);
        }
    };
    try
    {
        getContainer().run(true, true, op);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        Throwable realException = e.getTargetException();
        MessageDialog.openError(getShell(), "Error", realException.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    project = projectHandle;
    if (project == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.updatePerspective(config);
    BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.selectAndReveal(project, workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow());
    return true;
}
```

edit ***

ok so the solution is to add a facet to the project. if i do this manualy after creating a new project via my plugin - from right click, project properties - it works.
how to add this facet programmaticaly?

edit 2 ***

ok, so it is done via:

```
description.setNatureIds
```

but not quite.

here is how the project looks when i manually add the facet to it (and this is how i want it to look):

[image]

and this is how it actually looks when i add nature id "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature" programmaticaly (not how i want it)

[image]

**so... how to fix that?** do i need another nature?

here is the .project file content when i manually add the facet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>test</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

also the file .classpath gets added (when adding facet manually, but there is no such file when it gets added programmaticaly):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

here is also my method createProject():

```
private void createProject(IProjectDescription description, IProject proj, IProgressMonitor monitor)
            throws CoreException, OperationCanceledException
    {
        try
        {
            monitor.beginTask("", 2000);
            proj.create(description, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 10));
            if (monitor.isCanceled())
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            }
            proj.open(IResource.BACKGROUND_REFRESH, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 10));
            IContainer container = (IContainer) proj;
            [ *** ]
}
        finally
        {
            monitor.done();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your created project is missing Java and WST natures and builders.

```
desc.setNatureIds(new String[] {org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.NATURE_ID, "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature"});
org.eclipse.core.resources.ICommand[] commands = new ICommand[] { desc.newCommand(), desc.newCommand };
commands[0].setBuilderName(org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.BUILDER_ID);
commands[1].setBuilderName("org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder");
desc.setBuildSpec(commands);

createProject(...) {
...
proj.create(description, ...);
IFolder srcFolder = proj.getFolder(new Path("src"));
srcFolder.create(false, true, new NullProgressMonitor());
org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject javaProject = org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.create(proj);
org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry src = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(srcFolder.getFullPath());
IClasspathEntry jre = JavaCore.newContainerEntry(new Path(org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.JRE_CONTAINER), new IAccessRule[0], new IClasspathAttribute[] { JavaCore.newClasspathAttribute("owner.project.facets", "java")}, false);
IClasspathEntry[] entries = new IClasspathEntry[] { src, jre };
javaProject.setRawClasspath(entries, proj.getFullPath().append("bin"), new NullProgressMonitor());
```

Cheers,
Max

Comment: works, but not quite, see original question (i put images there ;) for better explanation.

Comment: when i copy the file .classpath from the manually added facet project, to the programmaticaly made one, this fixes it, but now the question is how to add the stuff in .classpath programmaticaly as well? i hope this will be the last step to fixing this :)

Comment: add org.eclipse.jdt.core and org.eclipse.jdt.launching into your plugin Dependencies (MANIFEST.MF)

Comment: you have the patience of a holy man :) just one more thing - when i run it (compile is fine) i get an error: IClasspathEntry must be absolute path.

Comment: thank you - had the code for that already just shifted it around :)

Comment: can award the bounty in 20 hours :) THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your plugin you could add the Java facet to the new project. Have a look at the  "Project Facets" setting, convert the project to faceted form if necessary and select Java as the facet to use. This should enable the settings you're looking for.

Comment: tried it manually in the project i made, seems to work - GREAT. you wouldn't happen to have a code on how to add the facet programmaticaly? if not, i will look myself, of course ;) anyhow thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that deep into plugin programming.